# inner height 100% with element above

Tags: html, css

I have two div's and I want to lower div to take up the rest of the page but when I height things in the bottom div they run off the screen.

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LTQkG/2/)

HTML:

```
<div id="full">
    <div id="header">This is the header content.</div>
    <div id="someid">
        <div id="someid2">
            Hello content    
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#full {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
#header,
#someid{
    display: table-row;
}
#header{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
}
#someid{
    background-color: green;
}
#someid2{
    background-color:red;
    height: 100%
}
```

I'd like the header part to only size to the height that it needs, not what looks to be 50%.
Should I be using display table row here?

Comment: at least it is supported in almost all browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=table

Answer (score 0):

Leave the display of the #header div as its default, 'block'.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LTQkG/3/

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#full {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
/* REMOVED #header selector here. */
#someid{
    display: table-row;
}
#header{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
}
#someid{
    background-color: green;
    height: auto;
}
#someid2{
    background-color:red;
    height: 100%
}
```

Comment: someID2 does not push up against #header could have been confused with the color updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LTQkG/6/